# primefaces drag and drop : content is not visible (behind other data) while dragging from datatable

Tags: primefaces

I implemented a drag and drop very similar to the one described in the primefaces drag drop datatable example (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf)

One column is draggable. 
However, when I drag the content (which is text) the content is not visible anymore once it gets out of the cell. 
I want to have it visible all the time, so when dragging over other columns, outside the table....

The showcase in primefaces has the same issue.

Anyone an idea ?

thx

Jo